# python print one line same space

Tags: python, loops, printing

I need to print 'ok' in same place. Any ways to do it?

I've found solutions but they don't works with IDLE correctly:

```
 while (count < 9):
      if statusm == "<Status>OK</Status>":
         print "ok",
```

I want every 'ok' on the same line. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by same place?

Comment: More information is needed to answer this. What do you mean by "same palce" and where are you printing to? A file, a Windows Terminal?

Comment: yes windows terminal

that code print ok ok ok ok ok without the , prints ok new line and other ok i just need one ok no more

Comment: @Gerswin Lee Could you rephrase your sentence in a comprehensible manner please ? "windows terminal that code print ok ok ok ok ok without the , prints ok new line" : what the hell does it mean ???

Comment: done, my mistake i was using IDLE

Comment: How can you tell when 'ok' is printed more once if it is printed in the same place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if you want to print "OK" in the exact same spot, you can do :

```
for i in range(0, 10000):
    print("\rOK", end='')
```

Result :

```
OK
```

worte 10000 times on the same console spot.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on python 2.7 + ipython. Anything I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

**Code:**

```
for i in range(5):
    print '\b\b\bok',
```

Or, if your 'ok' is at the beginning of the line you can use a single '\r' instead:

```
for i in range(5):
    print '\rok',
```

**Output:**

```
ok
```

Comment: And in general, '\r' will back up to the beginning of the line.

Comment: @GerswinLee Looks like windows terminals don't like the backspace character. You could try `\r` instead, but I suspect the result will be the same.

Comment: @GerswinLee [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667462/backspace-behavior-in-python-statement-what-is-correct-behavior-of-printing-a) seems to suggest that backspace should work in windows terminals. Can you replicate the results shown there?

Answer (score 0):

That ? :

```
from sys import stdout

count = 1    
statusm = "<Status>OK</Status>"
while (count < 9):
      if statusm == "<Status>OK</Status>":
          stdout.write('OK')
          count += 1
```

EDIT

I think it isn't possible to do just one OK, in IDLE. But the following code will give idea of what is possible in a console:

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

several = ("<Status>OK</Status>",
           "<Status>bad</Status>",
           "<Status>OK</Status>",
           "<Status>bad</Status>",
           "<Status>yes</Status>",
           "<Status>OK</Status>",
           "<Status>none</Status>",
           "<Status>bad</Status>",
           "<Status>OK</Status>",
           "<Status>yes</Status>")

good = ('OK','yes')

for i,status in enumerate(several):
    y = str(i)
    stdout.write(y)
    stdout.write(' OK' if any(x in status for x in good) else ' --')
    sleep(1.0)
    stdout.write('\b \b\b \b\b \b')
    for c in y:  stdout.write('\b \b')
```

result

```
OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK
```

Comment: just one ok, maybe is not possible

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print them one at a time, use one of the other answers.
This will print them all at once:

```
my_var = ''
while (count < 9):
      if statusm == "<Status>OK</Status>":
         my_var += 'ok'
print my_var
```