# <back space> not functional in python and ipython in shell

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ipython

**Python version** : Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit).

**Ipython version** : IPython 4.2.0

**Problem:**
Backspace key misbehaves. It brings the cursor forward a few spaces like the tab key...

I'm running bash version:
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

on linux manjaro 17.0.6 Gallivera.

kernel 4.9.58.1-manjaro

I expect it's the Anaconda Python installation as the python 2.7 behaves normally.

This version of Anaconda and IPython I can't really update, because of competability issues with Emacs-python-mode so I don't know in what way I can test what is causing the problem.

Comment: Does `^H` (control H) work?

Comment: when I run shell in emacs ( M-x shell) and run ipython there it works perfectly, What does that mean? It point that the problem is in bash, no?

Comment: @tadman . ^H doesn't work. It goes forward one space. and yes it does work in rhe shell generally, just not when python runs.

Comment: Seems like an `stty` issue of some sort. Most of these REPL tools use [readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) which is pretty good at picking up on your settings.

Comment: @tadman I believe newer versions of Ipython dropped `readline`: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version5.html#new-terminal-interface

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wonder if one of these uses `readline` and the other doesn't, and that's where the difference in behaviour comes from.

Comment: I don't have readline installed and no ~/.inputrc file as the article @juanpa.arrivillaga points at. Also the problem occurs on the simpler python repl and not only in ipython

Answer (score 26):

According to https://blog.csdn.net/qq_29695701/article/details/90715653

I added

```
export TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
```

to my .bashrc file and it worked!

For csh or tcsh, do this instead

```
setenv TERMINFO /usr/share/terminfo
```

Comment: Works like a charm and I prefer this solution over setting $TERM, because $TERM has influence on other programs such as vim or tmux.

Comment: For those on OSx Catalina you need to add to your .zshrc file. `nano ~/.zshrc`

Comment: This works fine for my ubuntu 18. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on RHEL 7.9, bash 4.2. Confused why it must go in .bashrc. Executing `TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo` in-line doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Miniconda (or something related to conda's Python) seems to have a problem with Manjaro's default [$TERM variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-TERM-variable.html). In my case, it was `rxvt-unicode-256color`. When I set it to `xterm`, the problem went away.

You can do this by running `export TERM=xterm`.

I'm still not sure why this problem occurs, and why only occasionally, but this fixed it for me.

Comment: This does not work for my ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I finally figured out.

**0x00 Cause**
I don't know for sure. But since re-install helps, I guess the previous version of python was not installed correctly.

**0x01 Solution (0 - recommended)**

> This is a better solution.

Reinstall conda by:

1. See all your environment by `conda activate` and `conda env list`
2. Back up **ALL** your current settings `conda env export -n {your_env_name} > {your_env_name}_condaenv.yml`
3. Uninstall conda (See [Official Guide](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux.html))
4. Reinstall conda (See [Official Guide](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html))
5. Import environments by `conda env create -f {file_name_you_saved}.yml`

**0x01 Solution (1 - not recommended)**

> WARNING: this solution only let you install a new python that works,
>   which is not recommended.

1. type `pip` see if you have installed pip
2. If you get `Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:
   sudo apt install python-pip` then you need to install `pip` first.
3. Check if the problem solved. If not, use `pip install gnureadline`
4. The problem should be solved.

**0x02 Possible Duplicates (but none of them are answered):**

1. https://superuser.com/questions/641095/bash-how-to-globally-fix-h-and-backspace-problems
2. [Backspace character weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856344/backspace-character-weirdness)

**0x03 Reference**

- https://blog.csdn.net/liang19890820/article/details/68063263